# ionic3/angular4 Lazy loading Don't work

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

CLI:

```
node -v 6.11.2 
cordova -v 6.5.0
ionic -v 3.9.2
```

Create an ionic tabs project with only the homepage(Manually deleted):

```
ionic start demo1 tabs
```

then create two pages use the cmd:

```
ionic g page Oneself
ionic g page Setting
```

this is app.module.ts code:

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
//import { SettingPage } from "../pages/setting/setting";
//import { OneselfPage } from "../pages/oneself/oneself";

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is oneself.module.ts like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OneselfPage } from './oneself';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OneselfPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OneselfPage),
  ],
  exports:[
    OneselfPage
  ]

})
export class OneselfPageModule {}
```

this is oneself.ts File Code like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the OneselfPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-oneself',
  templateUrl: 'oneself.html',
})
export class OneselfPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad OneselfPage');
  }
}
```

SettingPage Same as above；

this is tabs.ts code :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = "OneselfPage";//class name
  tab3Root = "SettingPage";//class name 
  constructor() {
    
  }
}
```

I know that lazy loading has several key points, such as declaring @ionicpage (), @ngmodule, IonicPageModule. ForChild (pageName)... I have such declarations in my code, but lazy loads don't work and the errors are as follows:

This is the first line error, and I don't know if it's related to lazy loading

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

The following error must have something to do with lazy loading :

```
Error {rejection: Error, promise: t, zone: r, task: t, stack: <accessor>, …}
message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../pages/oneself/oneself.module'.
Error: Cannot find module '../pages/oneself/oneself.module'
 at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:65357:9
    at t.invoke
```

See screen capture :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGTVN.jpg

Can someone help me answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the cordova ionic installed with cnpm has the problem,dont use cnpm install , use  npm install ,the lazy load is run.

Answer (score 0):

CLI:

```
node -v 8.2.1
cordova -v 7.0.1
ionic -v 3.9.2
```

I have followed what you have described

```
ionic start demo1 tabs
ionic g page Oneself
ionic g page Setting
```

I was unable to reproduce any of the errors that you were stating

`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

or

`Error {rejection: Error, promise: t, zone: r, task: t, stack: <accessor>, …}
message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../pages/oneself/oneself.module'.
Error: Cannot find module '../pages/oneself/oneself.module'
 at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:65357:9
    at t.invoke`

If you want to compare against [my reproduction of your scenario you can do so, hope this helps](https://github.com/Barlocker-Garrett/Ionic-Lazy-Loading-Demo)